# retrieve value from db in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a db in which 1 column value will be always null.I want it to pass to next page but it is passing all values of other column except this null value column.

This is my code

```
    $row=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `thirdpartycategorymaster` WHERE ISNULL(`delete`)");
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($row))
    {


  <td><b><a href="catdel.php?head1=<?php echo $row1['ThirdPartyCategoryName'] . '&&msg1=' . $row1['ThirdPartyCategoryID'] . '&&ctdel=' . $row1['delete']; ?> ">Delete</a></b></td>
```

This my db table

ThirdPartyCategoryID    ThirdPartyCategoryName  delete
                29               ecommerce      NULL

Comment: It's null, so what exactly do you want to pass on? The string "null" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// ...
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($row)) {
?>
  <td><b><a href="catdel.php?head=<?php echo $row1['ThirdPartyCategoryName'] ?>&amp;msg1=<?php echo $row1['ThirdPartyCategoryID']?>&amp;ctdel=<?php echo ((is_null($row1['delete'])) ? 'null' : $row1['delete']) ?>">Delete</a></b></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

untested ... but I think it will do what you need ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, a `null` value in MySQL translates to `null` in PHP.

If you concatenate a string with `null`, then you get the same string back (`null` becomes an empty string):

```
echo 'This is null: ' . null;
// prints This is null:
```

What exactly do you want to pass as values? The string `'null'`? If so, as all the entries hav e `null` in the field, you can just hardcode it:

```
echo $row1['ThirdPartyCategoryName'] . '&msg1=' . $row1['ThirdPartyCategoryID'] . '&ctdel=null';
```